# Effective Potential (inverted pendulum)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to figure out the effective potential of an inverted pendulum (with vertical oscillations). I found an article online that derives it for me but I'm not understanding one of the steps.

The equation of motion in this case is:
$$ \ddot\theta+\big( \frac{g}{l} + \frac{A\omega^2}{l}cos(\omega t) \big)\sin(\theta)=0 $$

They start by decomposing the motion into to functions: one function for the “smooth” motion (call it $ X(t) $) of the swinging pendulum another function for the “rapid” motion of the vibrating base (call it $ \xi(t) $) which translates (mathematically) into:

$$ \theta(t)=X(t)+\xi(t) $$

Now since $ \xi $ is small we can expand the equation of motion up to first order, this is:
$$ \ddot X + \ddot \xi = -\frac{g}{l}\sin(X)-\xi\frac{g}{l}\cos(X) - \frac{A\omega ^2}{l}\cos(\omega t)\sin(X) - \xi\frac{A\omega^2}{l}\cos(\omega t)\cos(X) $$

They then say "From here, we can equate the corresponding terms on the left and right sides of this equation. For the rapid motion, this is":
 $$ \ddot \xi = -\xi\frac{g}{l}\cos(X) - \frac{A\omega ^2}{l}\cos(\omega t)\sin(X) - \xi\frac{A\omega^2}{l}\cos(\omega t)\cos(X) $$

which is what I don't understand.

[Here is the article I mentioned (section 6.1)](http://math.arizona.edu/~gabitov/teaching/141/math_485/Midterm_Reports/Vibrating_pendulum_midterm_presentation.pdf)

Comment: Well, first term on the left and first on the right ar the standard pendulum. The rest, hence, must be due to the rapid base.